# Voice call using twilo in web application

Tags: java, web-applications, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

we are trying to use voice call for our web application.
we tried using below code:

```
public class MakeCall {
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "545XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String TWILIO_NUMBER = "+185XXXXXXXXX";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Account mainAccount = client.getAccount();
    CallFactory callFactory = mainAccount.getCallFactory();
    Map<String, String> callParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    callParams.put("From",TWILIO_NUMBER);
    callParams.put("To", "+919014512394");
    callParams.put("Url", "http://ahoy.twilio.com/voice/api/demo");
    Call call = callFactory.create(callParams);
    System.out.println(call.getSid());
  }
}
```

From above code,we are able to hear twilio customer voice i.e,Welcome to the Twilio voice demo app. Press 1 to hear the weather forecast tomorrow. Press 2 to hear a song. Press 3 to create or join a conference bridge. Press 4 to record your voice for 5 seconds.

Actually we want to speak with  other mobile number by calling from twilio number

Basically we are new to twilio API.Plz guide us
Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The code you've written will initiate a new call when you call that endpoint. If you want to initiate a new call and then connect to another number so the two of you can talk, you need to change that slightly do it [Dials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) the number for you.

Here's  afull working example that shows you how to pick who you want to speak with, and then dials that person.

```
package com.twilio;

import com.twilio.twiml.Gather;
import com.twilio.twiml.Method;
import com.twilio.twiml.Play;
import com.twilio.twiml.Say;
import com.twilio.twiml.TwiMLException;
import com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TwilioServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Create a dict of people we know.
        HashMap<String, String> callers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        callers.put("+14158675309", "Curious George");
        callers.put("+14158675310", "Boots");
        callers.put("+14158675311", "Virgil");

        String fromNumber = request.getParameter("From");
        String knownCaller = callers.get(fromNumber);
        String message;
        if (knownCaller == null) {
            // Use a generic message
            message = "Hello Monkey";
        } else {
            // Use the caller's name
            message = "Hello " + knownCaller;
        }

        // Create a TwiML response and add our friendly message.
        VoiceResponse twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
                .say(new Say.Builder(message).build())
                // Play an MP3 for incoming callers.
                .play(new Play.Builder("http://demo.twilio.com/hellomonkey/monkey.mp3").build())
                .gather(new Gather.Builder()
                        .action("/handle-key")
                        .method(Method.POST)
                        .numDigits(1)
                        .say(new Say
                                .Builder("To speak to a real monkey, press 1. Press any other key to start over.")
                                .build())
                        .build()
                )
                .build();

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        try {
            response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXml());
        } catch (TwiMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

1. You start off with a HashMap containing all your telephone numbers
2. Upon pressing a number, the /handle-key endpoint is called. This is where the logic for dialing another number happens

   ```
   package com.twilio;

   import com.twilio.twiml.Dial;
   import com.twilio.twiml.Number;
   import com.twilio.twiml.Say;
   import com.twilio.twiml.TwiMLException;
   import com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse;

   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class TwilioHandleKeyServlet extends HttpServlet {

       @Override
       public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

           String digits = request.getParameter("Digits");
           VoiceResponse twiml;
           // Check if the user pressed "1" on their phone
           if (digits != null && digits.equals("1")) {
               // Connect 310 555 1212 to the incoming caller.
               Number number = new Number.Builder("+13105551212").build();
               Dial dial = new Dial.Builder().number(number).build();

               // If the above dial failed, say an error message.
               Say say = new Say.Builder("The call failed, or the remote party hung up. Goodbye.").build();

               twiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).say(say).build();
           } else {
               // If they didn't press 1, redirect them to the TwilioServlet
               response.sendRedirect("/twiml");
               return;
           }

           response.setContentType("application/xml");
           try {
               response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXml());
           } catch (TwiMLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

You can read a full explanation of this and find other examples in this [quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/twiml/connect-call-to-second-person).

Hope this helps you out.